# Why Cancel All Operation do not remove all operations?

Tags: objective-c

```
[oqlMyOperationQueue cancelAllOperations];

PO([oqlMyOperationQueue operations]);
```

I still see a bunch of operations there.

```
2013-05-06 16:05:38.559  [oqlMyOperationQueue operations]: (
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x20222730>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x2041f7a0>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x20450830>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x20417bf0>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x2006d510>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x2000d150>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x20379810>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x2021f8f0>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x2045dca0>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x2024c670>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x2041b8e0>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x203d54a0>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x20442c80>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x20452930>",
    "<NSBlockOperation: 0x20363af0>"
)
```

But I've canceled all operations. So what's the problem?

Okay I know that one operation will remain on the queue if it's already executing. But why so many are left? The queue is serial.

Answer (score 5):

To quote the [`NSOperationQueue` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method sends a cancel message to all operations currently in the
>   queue. Queued operations are cancelled before they begin executing. If
>   an operation is already executing, it is up to that operation to
>   recognize the cancellation and stop what it is doing.

`cancelAllOperations` doesn't clear the queue, but instead notifies all operations currently in the queue that they are cancelled. To further quote from the doc (emphasis mine):

> **You cannot directly remove an operation from a queue after it has been added**. An operation remains in its queue until it reports that
>   it is finished with its task. Finishing its task does not necessarily
>   mean that the operation performed that task to completion. An
>   operation can also be canceled. **Canceling an operation object leaves
>   the object in the queue but notifies the object that it should abort
>   its task as quickly as possible.**

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus From the same docs `You cannot directly remove an operation from a queue after it has been added.`. You should create a new NSOperationQueue.

Comment: @JustSid please update your answer with a link to the docs and possibly by addition above.

Comment: If your NSBlockOperation is long-running and you need to cancel it, you will probably have to create your own NSOperation subclass to do so.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW9) (emphasis mine):

> This method sends a cancel message to all operations currently in the queue. Queued operations are cancelled before they begin executing. **If an operation is already executing, it is up to that operation to recognize the cancellation and stop what it is doing.**

Comment: If operations are canceled before they begin executing what are they doing in queued block?

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus The operation itself can decide if it wants to obey the cancelation or not. Think of canceling more as a hint to the operation that it shouldn't finish (or even start) its task.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this comment

> So how do I clear queues then?

Subclass `NSOperation`. Add a condition to check if the operation was cancelled or not at the beginning and before doing a data call to fetch image or whatever lengthy task the operation is doing.

```
if (!self.isCancelled) 
    // then do something 
else 
    return;
```

If operation does involve multiple data calls, its better to add the check before each call. This should stop the current operation from executing further. And remaining operations in queue would also be stopped.